# I can still see my ENV variables when I use them in Webpack

Tags: webpack, version-control, environment-variables

I am playing around with Webpack and using ENV variables.

One of my concerns that so far is that I can still see variables in my repository or in the code itself. This is what I have tried:

Using **dotenv-webpack** I can use the `.env` file I can hide them from version control (which is good), but the down side is that if I look in the bundle.js file I can search for them and still see them. Even if I have the webpack set to production, which makes me think what is the point?

Using **webpack.EnvironmentPlugin** I can store the ENV in the webpack.config.js file and I **do not** see them in my bundle.js file, but the webpack.config.js file is my version control - the only way around that is create private repositories.

I understand that using private repositories is always better if something is sensitive, but I am trying to see if I have missed a step with my current configuration.

In my head I would want to think that I can create a .env file **and** not have it show up in my production code regardless of the fact that my repo is private or not. Am I wrong in thinking that?

What am I missing?

**EXTRA**
I did see [this post on Github](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/386#issuecomment-192583352) but to me it still raises the question of being able to see the ENV vars on the version control side??

Answer (score 1):

*(Revised)*

Let's say you don't want to expose a configuration value in your repository. (In which case an env file that is not version-control is the answer). It might be:

- something *secret* you don't want to expose to anyone, e.g. a **private** API key;
- a piece of configuration that needs to be added based on each specific environment — for example, a **public** API key for something like a google service, e.g. Google Maps, that you want each user who gets your repo to set up themselves.

An env file is a a good choice for either type of config.

Some of these pieces of information you'll need to have in your bundled web application; a client-side web application will need an actual Google Maps API key for maps to work (and consequently, whoever uses your web app can find it in your bundle). This is where `dotenv-webpack` helps you place info from your env file in your JS bundle. You can't get to use the value of an env property in your web app without the users seeing what the value is.

Other pieces of information should not be exposed to users of your web apps — a username/password  to a database connection is an example; you can still keep them in your env file, but don't bundle them in your web app. You can still use them when **building** your app with Webpack, if you need to, but don't inject them in the bundle — which, in the case of `dotenv-webpack`, means not referencing them with `process.env.SOME_VAR` in your code.

Comment: Right, but I though the point of using an .env (in part) was so you can ignore in your version control, but I the webpack config **is** in your version-control so therefore your passwords or secret tokens are still searchable??

Comment: I'll try to expand my answer once I get to a proper keyboard :-)

Comment: Yeah it does thanks! So if I understand this correctly the principle is that since webpack creates bundles for the front-end, you should never use the ENV variables you want to keep a secret in there. They should be read into the app via a backed api. I guess my point of confusion is that things like a Google Maps api key I would still like to keep private - I don't see why you would want to expose any ENV variables. But maybe that is where I keep going around into circles.

Comment: To be more clear - what is the point of an api key if it can be read in the view source part of a browser when it is suppose to only give you access to data if you have the api key. If I can just use anyone token (public api ones) what is the point of the having the token?? See going in circles :-)